# Run Swagger UI with 2 different ports from VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, swagger

I have a application in VS2019.
I wan to run 2 different module of API with swagger UI and different ports.
Can any one help me?

Answer (score -1):

Your API should have 2 ports binded and then Swagger will be displayed for both with no extra configuration...
Example using .NET Core:

launchSettings.json:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
```

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

and in Startup.cs

-ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "NameOfAPI", Version = "v1" });
});
```

-Configure method:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "NameOfAPI");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

Comment: Can help me to Cerate 2 different Swagger UI for that which can run with two differnt version V1 and V2 ??