# Create 2 different Swagger UI for that which can run with two different version V1 and V2 in one application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, swagger

Create 2 different Swagger UI for that which can run with two different version V1 and V2 in one application.
I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Is this the same question as [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845049/run-swagger-ui-with-2-different-ports-from-vs)? Please don't post duplicate questions.

Comment: Sure , will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve the solution you are looking for, is to create different versions of your API. That is creating each version on as a separate folder under controller folder.

for example:

```
controllers/v1/{controllerName} for v1 endpoints
controllers/v2/{controllerName} for v2 endpoints
```

Then in each controller you specify the version and the route

```
for v1 endpoints

namespace SampleWebApiAspNetCore.v1.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class FoodsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("1.0");
        }
    }
}

for v2 endpoints

namespace SampleWebApiAspNetCore.v2.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class FoodsController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok("2.0");
        }
    }
}
```

Then to access these versions on swagger you have to configure swagger by implementing IConfigureOptions

```
public class ConfigureSwaggerOptions : IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>
    {
        readonly IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider;

        public ConfigureSwaggerOptions(IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider) => this.provider = provider;

        public void Configure(SwaggerGenOptions options)
        {
            foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc(description.GroupName, CreateInfoForApiVersion(description));
            }
        }

        static OpenApiInfo CreateInfoForApiVersion(ApiVersionDescription description)
        {
            var info = new OpenApiInfo()
            {
                Title = "Sample API",
                Version = description.ApiVersion.ToString(),
                Description = "A sample application with Swagger, Swashbuckle, and API versioning.",
            };

            if (description.IsDeprecated)
            {
                info.Description += " This API version has been deprecated.";
            }

            return info;
        }
    }
```

**>     In order to enable versioning you need to reference

> 

1. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning
2. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning.ApiExplorer

   from nuget package manager**

then on your startup configure versioning and add the swagger configuration as dependency

```
services.AddApiVersioning(
                config =>
                {
                    config.ReportApiVersions = true;
                    config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                    config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
                    config.ApiVersionReader = new HeaderApiVersionReader("api-version");
                });
            services.AddVersionedApiExplorer(
                options =>
                {
                    options.GroupNameFormat = "'v'VVV";

                    // note: this option is only necessary when versioning by url segment. the SubstitutionFormat
                    // can also be used to control the format of the API version in route templates
                    options.SubstituteApiVersionInUrl = true;
                });
            services.AddTransient<IConfigureOptions<SwaggerGenOptions>, ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

Your Startup Configure method will look like this

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider provider)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }


            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(
                options =>
                {
                    options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
                    foreach (var description in provider.ApiVersionDescriptions)
                    {
                        options.SwaggerEndpoint(
                            $"/swagger/{description.GroupName}/swagger.json",
                            description.GroupName.ToUpperInvariant());
                    }
                });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });

        }
```

each version will now have different url: https://localhost:5001/index.html?urls.primaryName=V1
https://localhost:5001/index.html?urls.primaryName=V2

or you can the switch different version from the Select a spec dropdown menu

All credits goes to Fabian Gosebrink

find the complete source code for more reference from https://github.com/FabianGosebrink/ASPNETCore-WebAPI-Sample

Happy Coding.

Comment: If it solves your problem don't forget to upvote and mark as answered